# Insert $ in front of numbers in column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to add dollar symbol in front of all the values in my column.

### Data

```
ID  Price
aa  800
bb  2
cc  300
cc  4
```

### Desired

```
ID  Price
aa  $800
bb  $2
cc  $300
cc  $4
```

### Doing

```
df.loc["Price"] ='$'+ df["Price"].map('{:,.0f}'.format)
```

I believe I have to map this, not 100% sure. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try

```
df["Price"] = '$' + df["Price"].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str.replace` here:

```py
df["Price"] = df["Price"].astype(str).str.replace(r'^', '$', regex=True)
```

Comment: thank you - when dong replace, must I always use this first code here? r'^'

Comment: There are other ways to go about this, I have given the regex approach.  `^` matches the start of the string.

Comment: for some reason this didn't work @Tim - not sure if it's because the column has integers